# Deboucing async property refresh

Tags: c#, system.reactive, throttling, debouncing

I would appreciate your help in the following problem:
A have a property in my class lets say

```
string Foo {get;set;}
```

There is a refresh function in the class. There is a long running method inside which updates the

```
Foo = await Task.Run()... etc.
```

How can I avoid stacking of the Task-s when 1000 Refresh is called per sec? Debouncing? Throttling? How to do that? Rx is available in the project and I am using dotnet core 2.2.

**Class Constructor**

```
    res = Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
                       await Task.Delay(5000);
                       return "Example";
    }
    )).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

**Class**

```
    private IObservable<string> res;

    public string Foo
    {
                get => _foo;
                set
                {
                    this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _foo, value);
                }
    }

    public void RefreshFoo()
    {
                res.Subscribe(x => Foo = x);
    }
```

Comment: Main problem is that you create new subscriptions every time you call `RefreshFoo`. What output do you expect if `RefreshFoo` is called "1000 times per sec" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use another package, I would suggest [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) and it's ReactiveCommand, which will handle all your problems out of the box:

```
  var command = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
            { // define the work
                Console.WriteLine("Executing at " + DateTime.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return "test";
            });

            command.Subscribe(res => {
                // do something with the result: assign to property
            });

            var d = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler) // you can specify scheduler if you want
                .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("Invoking at " + DateTime.Now))
                .Select(x => Unit.Default) // command argument type is Unit
                .InvokeCommand(command); // this checks command.CanExecute which is false while it is executing
```

outputs:

```
Invoking at 2019-01-22 13:34:04
Executing at 2019-01-22 13:34:04
Invoking at 2019-01-22 13:34:05
Invoking at 2019-01-22 13:34:05
Executing at 2019-01-22 13:34:05
```

I know that package is mostly used for UI development, but has few nice tricks, like ReactiveCommand that you can use everywhere.

Beware that `await command.Execute()` does not check by default if command can be executed.

I think this is much more readable than your solution.